# jquery visibility/hide/show/opacity

Tags: jquery

I have functionality like, when I browse the image it shows the preview & after some time it redirect to print command. This works properly but now the requirement is after browse the image don't display the preview, wait for a 10 seconds with message like "Please be patient till your image is ready for print." & after it should redirect to print command.

I have hide the image preview code but after 10 seconds it display the blank screen on print image. It does not display the image on print screen. Print command takes the area to print which was hide now.

Please suggest the solution as I don't want to display the image preview after browsed the image.

ID "printableArea" is print area which I have hide as it display the image preview.

```
 $("#printableArea").print({
    noPrintSelector: "#takeprint"
  });
```

[Click here to see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p61Tz.png)

Comment: Please post the code to show a sample of the issue.

Comment: Use a setTimeout function.

Comment: #printableArea contains the image preview code. If I set this section viewable i.e. $("#printableArea ").show() then above code for print working & shows the browsed the image on print page but when hide this area as $("#printableArea ").hide() & runs the code for print  then after it does not display the browsed image on print page..